# split csv file into multiple csv files based on a column value using fast-csv in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have a csv file say like this:

```
ID   Name   TNumber
123  John   123456
123  Joe    789012
124  Tim    896578
124  Tom    403796
```

I would like to split it into 2 separate csv files based on the `ID` column.

I am using `fast-csv` to parse and other modifications on the csv. I need to split the file into two (in the above case) and then do the other operations. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fastCsv = require('fast-csv');

const datas = {}; // data['123'] = CSV data filtered for id = 123
const options = {headers: true, delimiters: '\t'}; // relative to your CSV usage

fastCsv
    .fromPath('./data.csv', options)
    .on('data', d => {
        if (!datas[d.id]) datas[d.id] = [];
        datas[d.id].push(d)
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        Object.keys(datas).forEach(id => {
            // For each ID, write a new CSV file
            fastCsv
                .write(datas[id], options)
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./data-id-${id}.csv`));
        })
    });
```

Additionally this should be quite fast.

Comment: This looks beautifully useful. Unfortunately, when I tried it it output a csv named "data-id-undefined.csv" equivalent to the same tab del file from above. Also tried with comma separated. In FastCsv, aside from fromPath changing to parseFile, what else may keep it from working under Node 12.16.1 from 2020?